# SQLite3 With Unity3D

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I've been learning how to use sqlite3 with unity. I've got everything connected but now i need to know the Query to check if the username and password they entered exists.

So I've done this in python but it's not the same, i have a brief idea on how to do this.

SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ? - python way
is it any different?

My situation is this.

I've got two input fields, one username and the other password.

I need to check if username.text and password.text exists in the database.

if so goto the next scene and keep there username stored for later use.
I have the texts in a variable.

if anyone could lead me to a documentation or help me with this then that would be much appreciated.

Code:

http://pastebin.com/ePR5dvem
(Couldn't paste it in)

Comment: What's the question? Did you try your query?

Comment: Yes and i tried this instead.

string sqlQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username ="+username+" AND password ="+password;

But i need to know check if it exists if so then do something

Comment: So i've kind of done it, but i get a syntax error on the AND which is a correct operator According  to sqlite but i have no idea why it doesn't work